# How to display icons in QTableView via a custom QAbstractItemModel?

Tags: c++, qt, model

I'm building a custom QAbstractItemModel model.

The first column contains icons, the second one - text.

This is the code of the data method:

```
QVariant data ( const QModelIndex & index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole ) const
{
    if(role != Qt::DisplayRole )
        return QVariant();

    int col = index.column();
    if (col == 0)
    {
        return iconProvider->icon(QFileIconProvider::Folder);
    }
    else if (col == 1)
    {
        return "TEXT";
    }
}
```

But all I get in the resulting Table View is just text in the second column. There's no folder icon in the first column.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Did you delete your post, and then recreate it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Qt::DisplayRole` is only for text. Add:

```
if ( role == Qt::DecorationRole ) {
    return iconProvider->icon(QFileIconProvider::Folder);
}
```